# Django-Class based template HttpResponseRedirect does not redirect to desire page

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have the following code which will redirect to `localhost:3000/ocr/result` page, but it did not render the result page

```
class UploadView(generic.TemplateView): 
    template_name = 'ocr/upload.pug'      
    def get(self, request, args, *kwargs):        
    print 'Handling get request'
    response = TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name)
    return response

#@ensure_csrf_cookie
def post(self, request, args, *kwargs):
    print('Handling post request')
    #return HttpResponseRedirect('/ocr/result') 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('result')) 

class ResultView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ocr/result.pug'
```

`urls.py` looks like:

```
# ex: /ocr/upload/
url(r'^upload/$', views.UploadView.as_view(), name='upload'),
# ex: /ocr/result/
url(r'^result/$', views.ResultView.as_view(), name='result'),
```

When I used `return HttpResponseRedirect('/ocr/result')`, after processing post request, it did not render the result page `localhost:3000/ocr/result`, but still render upload page `localhost:3000/ocr/upload`. I dont understand why?

When I used `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('result'))`. It still has `error: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'result' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found`.

Could someone help me how to redirect to `/ocr/result` and render result page?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, and show the full urls.py file(s).

Comment: I fixed indentation, and I already found the reason why but still keeping this post for whom may encounter this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer. The problem is the post request did not come from `django` form. It came from `Dropzone.js` that using `Ajax` to send post request after uploaded. That why I could not redirect to another url after processing post method. By changing `onsuccess` event from `Dropzone` or create a Django form, I can successfully redirect to result page using code in my question. Thank you to one of my friends